# How to use `pandas.cut()` to bin the data based on a column other than the column being binned?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categories

I have a pandas DataFrame as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"first_column": ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7"],
        "second_column": ["cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2"],
        "third_column": [5, 1, 8, 3, 731, 189, 9]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
     first_column second_column  third_column
0        item1          cat1             5
1        item2          cat1             1
2        item3          cat1             8
3        item4          cat2             3
4        item5          cat2           731
5        item6          cat2           189
6        item7          cat2             9
```

Now, let's say I wanted to create a fourth column showing the classification of the third column using `pandas.cut()`. Here, I label each row whether the element in `third_column` is less than or equal to ten, `<=10`.

```
df["less_than_ten"]= pd.cut(df.third_column, [-np.inf, 10, np.inf], labels=(1,0))
```

And the resulting dataframe is now:

```
      first_column second_column  third_column less_than_ten
0        item1          cat1             5             1
1        item2          cat1             1             1
2        item3          cat1             8             1
3        item4          cat2             3             1
4        item5          cat2           731             0
5        item6          cat2           189             0
6        item7          cat2             9             1
```

Question: Notice the second column `second_column`, with categories `cat1` and `cat2`. How would I use `pandas.cut()` to reclassify these values based on the "class" in `second_column`?

For `cat1`, we can label 0 or 1 in the value in `third_column` is <=10. For `cat2`, we can label 2 or 3 in the value in `third_column` is <=10 (2 no, 3 yes).

This DataFrame would look like this:

```
      first_column second_column  third_column less_than_ten
0        item1          cat1             5             1
1        item2          cat1             1             1
2        item3          cat1             8             1
3        item4          cat2             3             3
4        item5          cat2           731             2
5        item6          cat2           189             2
6        item7          cat2             9             3
```

How does one do this? I'm binning the data of one column in the pandas dataframe, based on the categorical value of another column.

Answer (score 4):

- you don't need `pd.cut`.  you can just use `<= 10` and use it or cast it as an `int`.  `le(10)` is synonymous with `<= 10`
- in this particular case, you can create a dictionary to map with.  use it to convert your categories to integers that you can then add to the results of `le(10)`
- `assign` new column.  you could also have done this with `df['less_than_ten'] =` but I like `assign`

---

```
m = dict(cat1=0, cat2=2)
df.assign(less_than_ten=df.second_column.map(m) + df.third_column.le(10))

  first_column second_column  third_column  less_than_ten
0        item1          cat1             5              1
1        item2          cat1             1              1
2        item3          cat1             8              1
3        item4          cat2             3              3
4        item5          cat2           731              2
5        item6          cat2           189              2
6        item7          cat2             9              3
```

Comment: Thanks. Let's say I wanted more complex intervals, e.g. less or equal to 1000 `le(1000)` and greater than or equal to 20 `ge(20)`? How would this be done?

Comment: In this case, would I need `pd.cut()`?